# Sendgrid email is delivering, but doesn't include the form data

Tags: php, html, email, sendgrid

As the title states, the email is received, but just doesn't include all the data (name, email, phone, subject, message).

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';

//HTML grab
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$params = array(
    'api_user'  => "$user",
    'api_key'   => "$pass",
    'to'        => "email@gmail.com",
    'subject'   => "Submission Inquiry",
    'html'      => "<html><head><title> Contact Form</title><body>
   Name: $name\n<br>
   Email: $email\n<br>
   Subject: $subject\n<br>
   Message: $message <body></title></head></html>",
    'text'      => "
   Name: $name\n
   Email: $email\n
   Phone: $phone\n
   Subject: $subject\n
   $message",
    'from'      => "email@email.com",
  );


$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// Redirect to thank you page upon successfull completion, will want to build one if you don't alreday have one available
header('Location: ../success.html'); // feel free to use whatever title you wish for thank you landing page, but will need to reference that file name in place of the present 'thanks.html'
exit();

// print everything out
print_r($response);

?>
```

My site is http://geniecleaningcare.com

What am I doing wrong? This is my first time coding a PHP page! Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: Here is what the email body looks like:

```
--===============6352432520243076444==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


    Name:=20

    Email:=20

    Phone:=20

    Subject:=20

=20=20=20=20=

--===============6352432520243076444==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><head><title> Contact Form</title><body>
    Name:=20
<br>
    Email:=20
<br>
    Subject:=20
<br>
    Message:  <body></title></head></html>=

--===============6352432520243076444==--
```

There's some other data, but it's all related the head of the message or something.

Comment: does it include any body? view the email source

Comment: can we see the error you are getting, any log?

Comment: Added the info from the message. I am not sure what =20 means or where that's coming from. Also looks like the <body> tag at the bottom should be </body> instead? I changed it and tested it, still didn't work.

Comment: Just to rule out the frontend form, have you verified that the POST fields actually contain the correct data before you send the email?

Comment: Figured it out! I didn't add name="email" to the input fields on my HTML! Well now it works good. Thanks for making me check :-)

Answer (score 0):

I did not include the name=" " field in my  areas... so now it's:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="subject" class="required" name="subject">Subject</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" name="subject"> 
</div>
```

Works perfectly now.